# Any ideas on how to keep a refrigerator from moving without wheel locks?

Tags: floor, tile, refrigerator

I've got a frig on a tile floor without any wheel locks, and it likes to slide forward every time I open a refrigerator door quickly.  So far I have tried:

1. toilet shims shoved under the wheels.  Since they are plastic on
   ceramic tile, they kept sliding out.
2. I glued rubber toolbox liner to the toilet shims and tried again. They stayed longer this time, but still wind up coming out.

Does anyone have any tips on how to keep the refrigerator from moving forward when I open the door?

Comment: you can also use a stand which can be placed under the frig..

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Most refrigerators have adjustable feet that can be "unscrewed" in order to level the fridge.  All you need to do is "unscrew" these feet until the wheels are slightly off the floor.

Comment: I like this answer best - so I decided to try it.  I took the plastic cover off the front to try to get to the legs, and my fridge doesn't have those either!  I ended up jamming a screw through a spoke in the wheels so that the screw catches on the wheel mounts if it tries to roll.  Not the most ideal solution, but I'm hoping this one will stay put!

Comment: look at the fridge's installation manual, there must be a way to level it.

Answer (score 11):

What about [rubber furniture cups](http://www.homedepot.com/h_d1/N-5yc1v/R-100172405/h_d2/ProductDisplay?catalogId=10053&langId=-1&keyword=furniture%20leg%20rubber&storeId=10051)?

[image: furniturecups]

If they are not deep enough, you could cut a channel in the center to set the fridge leg/wheel deeper.

Answer (score 5):

I like Gunner's idea, but if your fridge doesn't have those legs, how about a rubber door stop? Slip it under the fridge and, if necessary, cut it off so it can (with friction) fit under the fridge and out of sight.
That doesn't give a ton of contact area with the fridge, but it may be enough depending on the Herculean force you exert when opening the door.

Answer (score 2):

The newer refrigerators do not have the old style feet that you would unscrew to make contact with the floor. You should first remove the front plastic toe kick  cover. Pry it gently with a scree driver wedged between the appliance and cover. There are 3 contact points. Once removed you will notice a hex head bolt in front of each caster.Turning this bolt clockwise will raise the refrigerator and counter wise will lower it. With this process I then placed a piece of floor tile under the front of the frame and then lowered the refrigerator directly onto the the tile. Thus resting the refrigerator onto the tile and not in the casters. To move the refrigerator in the future just raise it slightly off of the tile.

Answer (score 1):

My problem was fridge rolling back over time and hitting wall. Tried wooden rods, wedges, etc. but they just slid on the tile. Think I've solved problem by getting a rubber cord protector (what you use when you have an extension cord that needs to go across an aisle). Cut to size and wedged under front wheels of fridge. So far so good, rubber doesn't slide on tile the way wood did. Cord protector came with some double-sided tape, so if I notice any movement again I'll put some tape on each end of the protector.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the wheels from refrigerator

Comment: This seems like it would cause more problems than it solves.

Comment: When it comes time to move the frig you'll want the wheels.

Answer (score 0):

We just bought an upright freezer and it would move every time we opened the door.  First we lifted the front of the freezer with a hand truck.  We covered the base of the truck with a towel so it wouldn't damage the freezer.  We then cut out two small pieces of shelf liner under each front leg.  We used a liner that grips on shelves or anything you use it on.  This worked like a charm.  Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem just recently but and have tried numerous solutions but today at a boot fair found the perfect solution. Its called "the wedge" by BLUW. It could have been made to solve the problem. It consists of two soft rubber d shaped wedges designed to sit either side of a 
stack of wine bottles. But it slides perfectly in a space in front of the back wheels of my fridge and prevents any movement.